# Side effects of lambda expression in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Please consider the below code snippet.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
List<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Consumer<String> consumer = s->copyList.add(s);
list.stream().forEach(consumer);
```

Since we are using lambda expression, as per functional programming (pure functions) it should only compute the input & provide corresponding output.

But here in the example it is trying to add elements to the list which is neither input nor declared inside the lambda scope.

Is this a good practice, I mean, leading to any side effects?

Comment: Last lines can be refactored to `list.stream().forEach(copyList::add);`

Comment: `forEach` is never purely functional since without side effects it would not do anything with the stream. This is true for `for-each` in Scheme, `Array.forEach` in JS, ...

Answer (score 10):

`forEach` would be useless if it didn't produce side-effects, since it has no return value. Hence, whenever you use `forEach` you should be expecting side-effects to take place. Therefore there's nothing wrong with your example.

A `Consumer<String>` can print the `String`, or insert it into some database, or write it into some output file, or store it in some `Collection` (as in your example), etc...

From the `Stream` Javadoc:

> A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an array, a collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more intermediate operations (which transform a stream into another stream, such as Stream.filter(Predicate)), and a terminal operation (**which produces** a result **or side-effect**, such as Stream.count() or Stream.forEach(Consumer)).

Besides, if you look at the Javadoc of `Consumer`, you'll see that it's expected to have side-effects:

> **java.util.function.Consumer**
>
> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result. Unlike most other functional interfaces, **Consumer is expected to operate via side-effects**.

I guess this means Java `Stream`s and functional interfaces were not designed to be used only for "purely" functional programming.

Comment: More generally, Consumer is meant to produce side-effects by definition.

Answer (score 2):

For a `forEach` or even a `stream().forEach` it is pretty straightforward. **Your example works fine.**

Be aware though that if you would do this with other streaming methods, then you could get some surprises: e.g. **The following code prints absolutely nothing.**

```
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

lst.stream().map(
 s -> {
   System.out.println(s);
   return "-";
 });
```

In this case, the stream acts more **like a builder** which prepares a process but does not execute it yet. It's only when a `collect`, `count` or `find...` method is called that the lambda is executed.

An easy way to spot this, is by looking at the return type of the `map` method, which in turn is again a `Stream`.

**Having said that, I think for your specific example, there are easier alternatives.**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

// this is the base pattern for transforming one list to another.
// the map applies a transformation.
List<String> copyList1 = list.stream().map(e -> e).collect(Collectors.toList());

// if it's a 1-to-1 mapping, then you don't really need the map.
List<String> copyList2 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

// in essence, you could of course just clone the list without streaming.
List<String> copyList3 = new ArrayList<>(list);
```